# Where is update manager?

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

Software center dosent give me the option to upgrade my distribution, just programs, and I cant find update manager anywhere

Comment: No Ubuntu version given, I'm gonna assume it's 13.04?

Comment: Which version are you using and flavour as the answer will be different in each case?  Ubuntu 13.04, Kubuntu 12.04 for example, also let us know if you have changed the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the settings,it could be set to only accept long term release upgrades
you can upgrade using the `do-release-upgrade` command
the technical answer to the subject is `/usr/bin/update-manager`

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 i think, and i tried /usr/bin/update-manager returned software manager. its as if update manager isnt installed?

Comment: Ok, this was weird. i restarted my computer, and ubuntu somehow found 43 new software updates, plus a distribution update. How weird. Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: I am using 13.04, `/usr/bin/software-center` give me the software manager (i would not call that a manager, synaptic is a manager)